# Cannot turn off "sort" function in pandas.concat

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col3':np.random.randint(1,10,5),'col1':np.random.randint(30,80,5)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col4':np.random.randint(30,80,5),'col5':np.random.randint(100,130,5)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col9':np.random.randint(1,10,5),'col8':np.random.randint(30,80,5)})

x1 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1,sort=False)
x1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['I2'],x1.columns])
x2 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1,sort=False)
x2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['I3'],x2.columns])
x3 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1,sort=False)
x3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['I1'],x3.columns])

pd.concat([x1,x2,x3],axis=0,sort=False)
```

I was trying to get an aggregated dataframe with exactly the same column order as those of x1, x2 and x3 (which are already the same) as figure 1 shows below:

[Figure 1: I was trying to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoMw2.jpg)

But actually the above codes created a dataframe presented in figure 2 below:

[Figure 2: The code actually created this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOeqL.jpg)

1. I am wondering why the "sort=False" param did not successfully handle the sorting behaviour neither in the first level nor the second level of the columns in the pandas.concat() function?
2. Is there any other way that I can get the dataframe that I want?

Great thanks for your time and intelligence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use join instead of using concat

```
x1.join(x2,how='outer').join(x3,how='outer')
```

Result:

```
    I2                            I3                            I1                         
  col3 col1 col4 col5 col9 col8 col3 col1 col4 col5 col9 col8 col3 col1 col4 col5 col9 col8
0    7   54   42  128    8   79    7   54   42  128    8   79    7   54   42  128    8   79
1    1   56   56  102    1   77    1   56   56  102    1   77    1   56   56  102    1   77
2    9   34   52  108    4   68    9   34   52  108    4   68    9   34   52  108    4   68
3    3   42   51  108    8   75    3   42   51  108    8   75    3   42   51  108    8   75
4    3   34   70  100    5   78    3   34   70  100    5   78    3   34   70  100    5   78
```